# For the following system to be consistent, we must have $k \neq\;?$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I am helping with some math homework from WebWorK and am stumped.

The problem is asking:

> For the following system to be consistent,
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> 4x + 6y +7z &= 5\\
> -2x -3y +kz &= 6\\
> 8x +12y +29z &=26
> \end{align}
> $$
>      we must have $k\ne $ ?

We attempted to do the following, please point out any errors.

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
4 & 6 & 7 & 5\\ 
-2 & -3 & k & 6\\
8 & 12 & 29 & 26
\end{vmatrix}
$$

$r_1*2 \to r_1$

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
8 & 12 & 14 & 10\\ 
-2 & -3 & k & 6\\
8 & 12 & 29 & 26
\end{vmatrix}
$$

$r_3 - r_1 \to r_3$

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
8 & 12 & 14 & 10\\ 
-2 & -3 & k & 6\\
0 & 0 & 15 & 16
\end{vmatrix}
$$

We note that there is only a single solution to $z$

$r_2*4 \to r_2$

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
8 & 12 & 14 & 10\\ 
-8 & -12 & 4k & 24\\
0 & 0 & 15 & 16
\end{vmatrix}
$$

$r_1 + r_2 \to r_2$

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
8 & 12 & 14 & 10\\ 
0 & 0 & 14+4k & 34\\
0 & 0 & 15 & 16
\end{vmatrix}
$$

Uh Oh. $k$ is only a function of $z$

Specifically,
$$
(16/15)(14+4k)=34
$$

But that means (correct me if I am wrong) that there is only a single value for $k$ in which the system is consistent. So asking $k\ne$? doesn't make any sense.

Am I making any sense?

Comment: Not sure if this is the solution, but what if $k = -7/2$? Then you'd get something like $0 = 34$ which certainly sounds inconsistent to me!  That might have been what they were looking for--although your point is valid: there appears to be only a unique value for $k$. They may not have realized this when they wrote the problem!

Comment: We tried $143/32$ (the only consistent solution for k) thinking it was a typo and wanted $k=$? but it doesn't like that. We have also tried a few other random values including $-7/2$ but it doesn't like those either. We emailed the professor asking for assistance but it could be days before he responds. Posted here hoping our logic was in err.

Comment: Just for the record, is there a link to your exercise, or at least the site of WebWorK? It seems to be a [MAA web application](http://webwork.maa.org/) installed in many places, and I'm not sure the problems are everywhere the same.

Comment: I don't have a link. It is a web application installed in many places. I believe the problems are procedurally generated, so randomly being unsolvable isn't completely unreasonable.

Comment: The only information provided is what is in the quote above except the "?" at the end is an input box. I have triple checked the transcription numerous times.

Comment: @tsuckow Your analysis seems to be excellent.  Are you able to check a different student's webwork for the same issue?  One explanation might be that the procedural generation failed to preclude this type of degeneracy, which I guess is pretty subtle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting problem, indeed.

You would (and many would) think than any $k$ would work, except one for which the determinant is zero.

Alas, the determinant of $A=\left(\begin{matrix}
4 & 6 & 7\\
-2 & -3 & k\\
8 & 12 & 29
\end{matrix}\right)$ is zero, whatever the value of $k$.

This is obvious by a closer look at the first two columns: they are both multiple of $\left(\begin{matrix}
2\\
-1\\
4
\end{matrix}\right)$.

So, what does it mean? The system has no solution, except for one value of $k$ that makes the system consistent, and that's the value you found.

From your computations, you must have $z=\frac{16}{15}$ and $k=\frac14\left(34\cdot\frac{15}{16}-14\right)=\frac{143}{32}$. Then there are infinitely many solutions for $x,y$, given by the first equation $4x+6y+7z=5$ or $2x+3y=-\frac{37}{30}$: for any $x$, you have a working $y$. The general solution is thus:

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
x\\
-\frac{37}{90}-\frac23x\\
\frac{16}{15}
\end{matrix}\right)$$

By replacing in the equation, you can check that your calculations are right (I did).

Conclusion, you are right, the question does not make much sense. Or it may be on purpose, so that students don't see the trick too early. But this can't be the reason if you must answer something in a web application and there is no way to answer correctly.